# How private is private data on trello?

Tags: trello, privacy

I volunteer as a governor on a school governing board. Lots of people, teams, tasks (current, deferred and over-arching), meetings, committees, sub-committees, etc.

Trello would be an excellent tool for managing all of these complex tasks, ensuring none get dropped, and providing visibility to all. However, we have a legally binging duty of confidentiality.

So: since there is no locally installable product, how private is private? Can Fog Creek peruse the data? Or is it perhaps encrypted?

Comment: They don't mention data being encrypted on-disk, but of course your using SSL between the client browser and the Trello service.  See: https://trello.com/privacy

I imagine someone with more legal verse would be able to dig deeper into their TOS and decode the privacy issues.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It would depend on what kind of legal promise you needed.

Specific employees from Fog Creek have the ability to look at your data (sys admins, trello devs), although, as a company policy, these employees have all been instructed to get your permission first if they needed to do so.  General Fog Creek employees cannot access your data.

The data is not encrypted on our servers (so if someone were to hack into our system, the data on your boards could potentially be available to them).

You can also read more on our [Terms of Service](https://trello.com/legal), but the legal version says that Fog Creek makes "no warranty or representation regarding ... the security of the Service".

TLDR; We promise to try our best to keep your data secure and private.  We won't look at your data without your permission.  But legally we make no warranties about the security of the Service.

Comment: heh - looks like the admin staff are using a non-latest version of IE too... that could be an even bigger stumbling block, since Trello no-likey IE.

Comment: @MarcGravell It will work if you have them install chrome-frame. http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/

Comment: they tried unsuccessfully earlier; I'll take a look later when I go to collect my son ;p

Comment: we got it working to look at (IE8, chrome-frame); minor note - for something with obvious reach much wider than just tech folks, I wonder if it would be advantageous to support a *bit* more than just IE9 (on the IE front, I mean).